# Magento 2 - Change theme based on IP programmatically

Tags: magento2

Have tried to find a solution for this but can't find one anywhere.

I need to change the theme for a visitor based on their IP.

Any one have a clue where I can look?

(I'm trying to avoid the store front way - as the theme switch is only a temporary thing)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to give full details as I wasn't involved in the implementation, but I have worked on a site that does this so I'll try and explain how it works with my limited knowledge of it. Hopefully it helps a little bit.

- We have different store views each with their own theme
- We use some kind of GEO IP service which works out the users location based off their IP address
- There is them some logic to redirect them, along the lines of `document.location='http://'+location.hostname+'/'+realLocation;` in JS.
- I think there is something set in the NGINX/APACHE config to load a certain theme based on the country code. For example `url.com/uk` or `url.com/nl`.
- A cookie is set for future visits

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to avoid going down the store front route as it is only a temporary measure. I'll update my question to state this.Thanks